# Need for RestApi authentication

Tags: ajax, rest, authentication, vcloud-director-rest-api

Developed Rest API using Java/Spring MVC

1. Can we provide authentication for RestAPI? If yes, How?
2. Now I am struggling with authentication for RestApi. Can anyone send some examples regarding the same.
3. Accessing rest API through AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Spring, you can use [Spring security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) to provide security related functionality. This can give you one stop solution for your security needs. Common security mechanisms for Rest API's (basic, digest) and features are supported out of box and it's very easy to add your custom security too. For a start tutorial  you can have a look [here](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/)

Comment: Hi Shailendra,

We have developed RestApi for Mobile/Web application. By using Ajax request accessing RestApi. Can we provide authentication for each and every Ajax request. Already worked for spring security page blocking based on user role. How can provide authentication for method  level access. 


Thanks

senthilkumaran